# Windows 7 64 - Not Connected to network - But I am connected to router & Internet

Tags: windows-7, networking, router

On my Windows 7 64 bit, when it boots it connects to my router and Internet access is available. I get a clean Network Icon in system tray. However clicking that icon pops up 'Not connected, no connections are available' box with red X on bigger Network Icon in that box.

When I click on 'Open Network & sharing Center' it shows 'You are currently not connected to any networks'

This issue has recently come up. Searching google takes me to a similar issue on Microsoft site. I have tried possible solutions mentioned therein

1. Set Network Location Awareness service to auto start & reboot
2. Tried granting full permissions to 
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList  to account NETWORK SERVICE & reboot (I hop I have done it correctly)

However the issue  remains. As a result I can not add VPN connection.  Here's a snapshot of how it looks.

[image]

Would be glad to know further pointers to resolve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Just turn the network icon off. You don't need it.

Comment: @CConard96 Yikes! Adding those identities to the local Administrators group seriously lessens the security of the system. Those identities are intentionally low privileged and should remain that way.